# How to create indentation before the figure index of a caption

Tags: captions, indentation, revtex

I need to include subfigures in my file with documentclass  {revtex4-1}. As the caption package is incompatible with the class, I used \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}, but then the problem is that all the indentations before figure indices of a caption disappear. Is there any easy way to solve this issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It would be useful to those willing to help if you posted a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).